# Check if the current time between specific time

Tags: php

In my database have start time and end time 24h format.I write a function to show result depend on time.

```
$day_start=06:00;
$day_end=22:59;

$night_start=23:00;
$night_end=05:59;

$dtarif=30USD;
$ntarif=80USD;

function showtarif($day_start,$day_end,$night_start,$night_end,$dtarif,$ntarif)
{


$current=date("H:i");

    if ($current =>$day_start && $current <=$day_end) {

    $absulate_tarif=$dtarif;

    }
    else if ($current >=$night_start && $current <=$night_end) {
       $absulate_tarif=$ntarif;
    }

 return $absulate_tarif;
}
```

when i call my function the it always show null.

Comment: try wrapping strtotime() around. So $day_start=strtotime('06:00'); etc. You are comparing strings and not time as you would want. You need to compare time, either the difference in seconds or some other way.

Comment: What @va5ja said + Strings need Quotes, otherwise they will become integers: use `$ntarif = "80USD";` otherwise $ntarif becomes just 80.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember two things:

1. The comparison operators `>=` and `<=` are unable to compare strings. For that the built-in function [`strcmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) is needed.
2. A function can access only those variables which have been created *inside* the function (unless used with the `global` keyword).

In my opinion, you shouldn’t create variables like `$day_start`, `$day_end`, `$night_start`, `$night_end`, `$dtarif` and `$ntarif`. Just put their values at the right places and make your code more concise:

```
function showtarif(){
$current = date("H:i");
    if(strcmp($current, "06:00") >= 0 && strcmp($current, "22:59") <= 0){
    return "30USD";
    }
return "80USD";
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/134948)

Comment: when i call this function and value come from parameter then my time converted like 06:00 to 4321

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your time and amount in quotes

```
$day_start="06:00";
$day_end="22:59";

$night_start="23:00";
$night_end="05:59";

$dtarif="30USD";
$ntarif="80USD";
```